# Why some users in some SE sites have 101 reputation since the beginning?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

I saw some users in some SE sites that have 101 reputation since the beginbing without any question or answer. How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different sites in the Stack Exchange network, but accounts  on different sites can be linked.

If one reaches at least 200 points on one site, then one gets an automatic bonus of 100 points on every site where one has an account. This is called association bonus. See the [the official blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) for further details.

Thus, for example somebody having 6323 points on [math.se] and creating an account here will seem to start with 101, as 1 + 100 bonus.

(Minor detail: In rare situations, in particular for answering protected questions, these bonus points are not taken into account.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: I just checked.  I have 38 accounts on SE. 19 have 101 rep. Sites I just peeked at, and may still visit, but not ask or answer.